# How to make client side and server side communicate?

Tags: apache, server, browsers

I have apache installed, and I would like (using php/and or javascript, html) to do the following but I do not know how.

1. To send my client to the server a value x
2. The server to increase x by one and to send it to client
3. Client divides it by two and sends it to server
4. server send the h((x+1)/2) back to client

How I can do that?... I am confused as I do not know how to make a server and a browser to communicate. |However, I do not thing that it is very difficult...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe http://host/?value=x and $__GET['value'] would give you some insight to provide me more detailed question.

Answer (score 1):

You would like to use Ajax. I would recommend you use some kind of javascript library to handle the ajax calls.

> "With Ajax, web applications can send data to and retrieve data from a
>   server."

Here is a sample.

**Javascript** (jquery)

```
var x, divided, result;
x = 6;

divided = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "serverside.php?x=" + x,
    cache: false,
    async: false
    }).responseText;

divided = divided / 2;

result = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "serverside.php?laststage=" + divided,
    cache: false,
    async: false
    }).responseText;

alert(result);
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['x'])) {
    $x = $_GET['x'];
    $x++;
    echo $x;
}

if (isset($_GET['laststage'])) {
    echo $_GET['laststage'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you use555. I guess I'll have to go to bed now, but I will definitely try it tomorrow :) I vote up your answer for your time spend at my question and your effort:) Tomorrow I will try all the answers, and choose as best answer the answer that solves better my problem. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: edit: I just found out that I do not have enough reputation to vote up. As soon as I get, I'll definitely vote up your answer. Excuse me.. my mistake..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple PHP script to get you started:

```
<?php 
 if($_GET['v']){
   echo intval($_GET['v'])+1;
 }
?>

<form>
Enter a value: <input type=text name=v>
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

I saved that as `test.php` in my www documents folder.  The I opened it as `http://localhost/test.php` and was able to submit a number and verify that the script added 1 to it and showed me the result.

Comment: Thank you Stephen. I guess I'll have to go to bed now, but I will definitely try it tomorrow :) I vote up your answer for your time spend at my question and your effort:) Tomorrow I will try all the answers, and choose as best answer the answer that solves better my problem. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: edit: I just found out that I do not have enough reputation to vote up. As soon as I get, I'll definitely vote up your answer. Excuse me.. my mistake..